# UNION ALL does not echo out additional text

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

This is my code:

```
<?php
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("
    SELECT valueA, 'TEXT' AS valueAA FROM tableA
    UNION ALL
    SELECT valueB, 'TEXT2' FROM tableB;
");
$stmt->execute();
$points = $stmt->fetchAll();

foreach($rows as $row):
$valueA = htmlentities($row['valueA']);
$valueAVAR = number_format($valueA);
?>
<div><?php echo $valueAA . $valueAVAR; ?></div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

This is the unwanted result I am getting:

```
valueA
valueB
```

This is the result I **want**:

```
TEXTvalueA
TEXT2valueB
```

So basically, my code is not echoing out the word `TEXT` before `valueA` and `valueB` as it should based on my SQL statement. Can you please help me rewrite my code so `TEXT` can get echoed out? Thank you

EDIT: Sample of `tableA`:

```
valAid (int11) | valueA (int11)
  1            | 100
```

`tableB`:

```
valBid (int11) | valueB (int11)
  2            | 200
```

Comment: why wouldn't you add "TEXT" in the php instead of the query?  its the more logical approach

Comment: @tim ok I guess I missed something in my question. I edited the question, but they are different words being echoed out depending on values from the database. Luckily ChrisFNZ resolved this issue.

Comment: i would still be doing that in the php, its not logical to use the db for that.

Comment: @tim Hm.. I didn't think about that. I'll definitely take your advice and consider rewriting my code. It's because that I had tried the text rendering part with php alone, but code would not work out since I was using LEFT/INNER JOINS which resulted in duplicating all my rows (an unwanted result). So someone suggested using UNION ALL, which resolved that issue. But I'm reconsidering finding a fix with using just php. Thanks for the good advice

Comment: The best advise you can get is to quit this union stuff and have just a single table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a SELECT UNION to work then you'll need to ensure that the column names (aliases) are the same for both rows.

So instead of:

```
SELECT valueA, 'TEXT' AS valueAA FROM tableA
UNION ALL
SELECT valueB, 'TEXT' FROM tableB;
```

Would this give you closer to what you want?

```
SELECT valueA AS valFirst, 'TEXT' AS valSecond FROM tableA
UNION ALL
SELECT valueB AS valFirst, 'TEXT' AS valSecond FROM tableB;
```

Comment: YES! You saved me big time! Yours is the solution I was looking for - completely fixed my code. Seriously, thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome!  I'm stoked that my advice was useful.

Comment: Even a tiny bit of help can save a person's life! I am forever grateful to the people of this community. Not even in real life are people this nice enough to offer advice!

Answer (score 0):

I was in the process of writing this and saw Tim's comment, which is exactly what I was going to say. It seems much easier to add the string "TEXT" to the information you want in the PHP instead of the SQL. Here is an example:

```
echo "TEXT" . $valueAA . $valueAVAR;
```

Comment: yes it does, but I reedited my question because I missed something. The word "TEXT" is always a different value depending on what it is on the database. But ChrisFNZ resolved this issue, thanks too!

Answer (score 0):

You never read your field `valueAA` from your query.

```
<?php
...
foreach($rows as $row):
$valueA = htmlentities($row['valueA']);
$valueAVAR = number_format($valueA);
# read valueAA
$valueAA = htmlentities($row['valueAA']);
...
?>
<div><?php echo $valueAA . $valueAVAR; ?></div>
```

Comment: @OliverDepriester oh wow this was the solution too. I can't believe I completely missed that valueAA wasn't even echoed out as a row. Assumed that since it was a made-up one, it didn't need to be echoed out. But you cleared things up on the explanation part - thank you!

Comment: Great, because I was surprised @ChrisFNZ's answer was the solution as, as far as I know, UNION ALL does not care about the aliases. So I think your query could remain the same.